# Inserting large amount of records in MySQL database eats up memory

Tags: php, mysql, memory-leaks

I run a script on my server which inserts about 3000 records each minute of each ~2kB. It appears that the memory of the server gets clogged up with data from this activity. (100MB in 20min)

Eventually, I have to kill processes (HTTPD and MySQLd) or even restart the server to get back the memory...

Is there any way to conserve memory when inserting a large amount of records? It seems that MySQL somehow caches the inserted data...

Thanks!

Comment: That's a feature, not a bug.  Perhaps try `COMMIT` once in a while?

Comment: Have you tried mysql_free_result?

Comment: 100MB in 20min is nothing impressive, could you detail the problem? How do you insert the rows? From where are they coming?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I'm not saying that 100MB is a lot, but after 2 days, the memory is a bit full :D

I'll try to include a COMMIT. I think it's best to do that once in a while (eg every few minutes) and I'll have a look at mysql_free_result!

Answer (score 0):

**turning mysql cache off?**
just disable it: (taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html))

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 40000;   # minimum as docs says
SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;
```

you can give `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foo';` to check what these values contain.

Comment: Currently the query_cache_size is set to 0 and query_cache_type = ON. I find it kind-a odd that an INSERT can benefit from a cache, but as wallyk tells me, this is a feature...

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of improving insert performance.

First of all, do you have the possibility of sendind those inserts in one query per ten seconds? Or something similar. Here the idea would be to send less queries to the server.

Also, do you use InnoDB? That engine is better for this type uf usage.

Comment: It's an MyISAM database... I'm not familiar with the different database types (kinda newbie :) I'll have a look then at these types... 

I'll combine also some inserts, but that'll only delay the inevitable. I hope that the other solutions together help keeping memory in check!

Comment: You are going to be surprised what improvements you may reach if you find the optimal solution for the above.

Comment: A little update on the development: I've changed the database engine to InnoDB. While this results in a much larger database, it does support transactions. This resulted in a lower memory usage (COMMIT helped to manage memory usage). Disabling cache was the second largest change. Sadly, mysql_free_result did not work, as it appears not to work on INSERT queries...

Comment: Sadly, the problem still hasn't been fully resolved. Now the memory is filling up less fast, but it still is filling up. Is there any way to reset the memory taken up by MySQL so as to avoid memory filling up completely after a few days?

Comment: How often are you sending the queries to the database server? You may play a bit with that, like increase the time between two queries by sending more data in one insert.

Comment: That's correct, I now join queries, and insert 50 records at once. However, still, after 2 days of running, I will have to restart the server as memory is completely full... I continue to look for a more permanent solution :) I will keep you posted!